# How to filter ManyToManyField with distinct?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am using Django+postgres and have this model:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    type = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

`room` table data example:

```
____________________
| id      | type  |
|--------------------
| 1       | 1     |
| 2       | 1     |
| 3       | 2     |
 ...
```

`room_users` table data example:

```
____________________
| room_id | user_id |
|--------------------
| 1       | 100     |
| 1       | 101     |
| 2       | 100     |
| 2       | 102     |
| 3       | 103     |
 ...
```

**Q**: How to get `room_id` where **only** 2 users are participated and room has `type=1`? As you know, `ManyToManyField` automatically creates `room_users` table. Here is example code if I access directly to `room_users`, but I don't know how (`room_users` does not presented in django as model because of `ManyToManyField`):

```
user_id_1 = 100
user_id_2 = 101    
rooms = Room.objects.filter(users__in=[user_id_1, user_id_2], type=1).distinct("users__room_id").values_list("users__room_id", flat=True)
# result must me rooms[0].id = 1, len(rooms) = 1
```

For this case error is:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'room_id' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions, username
```

Comment: I understood that you want to find room number where user1 and user2 have together right? why don't you just query like `Room.objects.filter(users__in=[user_id_1, user_id_2], type=1).distinct("id").values_list("id", flat=True)`?

Comment: Because it prints wrong answer. It prints all room ids where finds `user_id_1` and `user_id_2`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it is the best way to solve your problem when you consider of performance.

My idea

```
user1 = User.objects.get(id=100).room_set.all()
user2 = User.objects.get(id=101).room_set.all()

same_room = user1.intersection(user2)
```

check [Django manual about intersection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#intersection) if you need

Answer (score 0):

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(type=1)
rooms = rooms.annotate(num_guests=Count('users')).filter(num_guests=2)
```

I added another room of type 1 to test, and one user stayed in the room
Using the shell the final get 2, I preferred to do this in 2 parts

[image: To get the detail, iterate over the queryset]

Comment: thank you for reply. where are `user_id_1` and `user_id_2` in your answer?

Comment: I updated the example. Your criteria was: get room_id where only 2 users are participated and room has type=1.  
Are you going to hard code in user ids to filter each time?

Comment: @sirjay did you try the revision?